# Are (55, 165, 495, 1485) and (286, 1716, 10296, 61776) the only geometric sequences of length 4 among non-trivial binomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, binomial-coefficients

Let's define **non-trivial binomial coefficients** as values of $\binom{n}{k}$, where $n$ and $k$ are positive integers such that $2 \le k \le \frac{n}{2}$. (Therefore, $6$ is the smallest non-trivial binomial coefficient, since it is $\binom42$.)

I noticed that $55, 165, 495, 1485$ is a geometric sequence of non-trivial binomial coefficients. <s>I conjecture that this is the only such geometric sequence of length 4 in Pascal's triangle</s> (UPD: there is also $286, 1716, 10296, 61776$ - hence disproved by [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457719/is-55-165-495-1485-the-only-geometric-sequence-of-length-4-among-non-trivial#comment1185620_457719); still, I wonder if there are any others - including those with non-integer ratios!).

To illustrate this:

- $\binom{11}{2} = 55$
- $\binom{11}{3} = 165$
- $\binom{12}{4} = 495$
- $\binom{55}{2} = 1485$

How would we tackle this problem? Any thoughts, even partial results, are welcome!

---

Note: As for geometric sequences in Pascal's triangle, I haven't found much material. This may be tangentially related, however: [Rows in Pascal's Triangle containing Numbers in Geometric Sequence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rows_in_Pascal%27s_Triangle_containing_Numbers_in_Geometric_Sequence).

Comment: On what basis do you make this conjecture?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}13\\3\end{pmatrix} = 286$, $\begin{pmatrix}13\\6\end{pmatrix} = 1716 = 286\cdot 6$, $\begin{pmatrix}144\\2\end{pmatrix} = 10296 = 286\cdot 6^2$, $\begin{pmatrix}352\\2\end{pmatrix} = 61776 = 286\cdot 6^3$ is another length-4 sequence.

Comment: 55,165,495,1485 and 286,1716,10296,61776 are the only sequences of length 4 under $2^{31}$.  There are no sequences of length 5.

Comment: No more with 4th value less than $2\times10^{12}$.  It would be possible to go further, because the binomials get very sparse (only 2027237 less than $2\times10^{12}$) but not with my program.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay To clarify, no sequences of length $5$ (with maximum) *under $2^{31}$*?

Comment: @mathwork21  No sequences of length 5 with maximum under $2\times 10^{12}$.  Since the next term of the two sequences of length 4 would be less than $2\times 10^{12}$, we can make a slightly stronger statement: No sequences of length 5 with the 4th term under $2\times 10^{12}$.

Comment: Joachim has correctly pointed out that I'm assuming the ratios are integers. I will fix that assumption tomorrow and take the computation to larger sizes.

Comment: One might ask the same question specifically among the binomials $\binom{n}{2}$, where it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Please ignore the numbers in my comments here and instead look at my partial answer.

Answer (score 16):

(Partial results.)

For the case of integer ratio, there are only two sequences of 4 binomials in geometric progression for which the largest is at most $10^{17}$. Namely, 55,165,495,1485 found by William and 286,1716,10296,61776 found by Joachim.

If non-integer ratio is allowed, there are no more examples of 4 binomials in geometric progression for which the largest is at most $10^{13}$.

A smarter search, in case someone is eager, would use the fact that the ratio must have the form $\frac ab$ where $b^3$ is a divisor of the smallest binomial. That should allow the general (not-necessarily-integer ratio) case to be taken up to $10^{15}$ or more.

=======

For the record, here are all triples in geometric progression for which the largest is at most $2\times 10^{12}$ and the ratio is an integer.

```
6 84 1176 (14)
15 330 7260 (22)
20 1140 64980 (57)
28 84 252 (3)
55 165 495 (3)
70 210 630 (3)
91 1365 20475 (15)
165 495 1485 (3)
231 462 924 (2)
286 1716 10296 (6)
455 1365 4095 (3)
715 2145 6435 (3)
969 3876 15504 (4)
1716 10296 61776 (6)
1820 988260 536625180 (543)
2926 8778 26334 (3)
3003 930930 288588300 (310)
23751 118755 593775 (5)
57155 12002550 2520535500 (210)
125580 225792840 405975526320 (1798)
135751 407253 1221759 (3)
211876 635628 1906884 (3)
749398 4496388 26978328 (6)
28989675 202927725 1420494075 (7)
1329890705 10639125640 85113005120 (8)
```

This suggests an infinite sequence of triples:
$$ \binom{n^2+n-1}{n-1}, \binom{n^2+n-1}{n}, \binom{n^2+n}{n+1},$$
which have a ratio of $n$.

The weird one with ratio 1798 is
$$\binom{92}{3}, \binom{32}{12}, \binom{13456}{3}. $$

As Joachim pointed out, there are also examples with non-integer ratio.  Here are all of them with the largest binomial less than $10^{10}$.

```
36 210 1225 (35/6)
56 84 126 (3/2)
220 330 495 (3/2)
1225 7140 41616 (204/35)
27405 118755 514605 (13/3)
41616 242556 1413721 (1189/204)
1413721 8239770 48024900 (6930/1189)
2496144 3744216 5616324 (3/2)
9962680 133784560 1796535520 (94/7)
48024900 279909630 1631432881 (40391/6930)
```

The last one is $$\binom{9801}{2}, \binom{23661}{2}, \binom{57122}{2}.$$

=====

Here are all cases $a < b < c$ where $\binom a2, \binom b2, \binom c2$ are in geometric progression and $c\le 4000000$. Note that this time I'm listing the numerators, not the binomial value. The ones in William's infinite series are marked with an asterisk.  None of them extend to a fourth term. An obvious question is whether William found all but finitely many of them.

```
2 4 9
9 21 50 *
50 120 289 *
78 1365 24025
289 697 1682 *
1682 4060 9801 *
9801 23661 57122 *
57122 137904 332929 *
332929 803761 1940450 *
```

Comment: You seem to assume the ratio to be integral, but I don't see this assumption in the original question. Without this assumption, there are several more examples of triples; this might possibly also affect your completeness statements in the comments above.

Comment: @JoachimKönig  That's a good point. I did indeed make that assumption, and so my comments may be incomplete.  Now it is past 1am so I'll take care of that tomorrow.  I should still be able to go up to $10^{17}$ or so.

Comment: I have edited in the answer/comment to specify "integer ratio", per @JoachimKönig's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457719/are-55-165-495-1485-and-286-1716-10296-61776-the-only-geometric-sequen#comment1185667_457737), until you have time to see the difference, if any, that allowing non-integer ratios makes.

Comment: These non-integer ratios actually show an infinite sequence of non-integer ratio triples too! Let $(1 + \sqrt2)^n = a_n + b_n\sqrt2$ for integers $a_n,b_n$. Then, $(a_nb_n)^2, (a_nb_n)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1}), (a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2$ form such a sequence!

Comment: Rough explanation of why: $(a_n, b_n)$ is a solution to Pell's equation $x^2 - 2y^2 = (-1)^n$. So, $a_n^2$ and $2b_n^2$ are consecutive integers. Thus, $(a_nb_n)^2$ is a triangular number. Now as for the middle term, you could show that $a_na_{n+1} - 2b_nb_{n+1} = \pm 1$: $a_na_{n+1} - 2b_nb_{n+1} = a_n(a_n + 2b_n) - 2b_n(a_n+b_n) = a_n^2 - 2b_n^2 = (-1)^n$. So the middle term is also a triangular number!

Comment: The question of three triangular numbers in geometric progression is equivalent to solutions in odd positive $x,y,z$ with $x\ne y$ of $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=(z^2-1)^2$. This equation is discussed in Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd ed., section D23. It says Gérardin found an infinity of solutions: if the $n$th triangular number, $t_n$, is a square, $m^2$, then $t_n,t_{n+2m},t_{3n+4m+1}$ are in geometric progression. Szymiczek found a triple not of this form: $t_{77},t_{1364},t_{24024}$ are in GP. Sierpiński asked whether there are four triangular numbers in GP; Szymiczek conjectured "No".

Comment: Also, "Ronald van Luijk observes that the equation represents a singular $K3$ surface with an elliptic fibration of positive rank, so that the rational points are dense. [...a correspondent writes that 'it can certainly be approached with the relatively standard technique of computing the Neron-Severi group, in order to find parametrizable curves of small degree.']"

Comment: @Gerry It seems by $t_n$ you mean $\binom{n+1}{2}$, not $\binom{n}{2}$. Right?  The first 7 of this infinite sequence match William's and I wonder if that's always true.

Comment: Yes, Brendan, I think that's the convention Guy was using. $t_n=m^2$ reduces to a Pell equation, the solutions satisfy a recurrence, and I expect the Gérardin-Szymiczek formulas come to the same thing as William's. Unfortunately, Guy gives no reference for Gérardin, and I couldn't find the Szymiczek paper, The equation $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=(z^2-1)^2$, Eureka 35 (1972) 21-25, online.

Comment: Maciej Ulas, On the Diophantine equation $(x^2+k)(y^2+k)=(z^2+k)^2$, Rocky Mountain J Math 38 (2008) 2091-2097, available at file:///Users/gmyerson/Downloads/RMJ-2008-38-6-2091.pdf may be worth a look.

Comment: Yong-Gao Chen and Jin-Hui Fang, Triangular numbers in geometric progression, Integers 7 (2007) A19, available via http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol7.html, says, "In this paper we prove that there do not exist four distinct triangular numbers in geometric progression." The paper is short and elementary. Also, the Gérardin paper is cited as A. Gerardin, Sphinx-Oedipe 9 (1914),75,145-146.

Comment: Sorry for necropost, but I've wondered about geometric series where the _middle_ term is missing! I've found these examples:
$\binom{14}{4} = 1001$, $\binom{14}{5} = 2002$, $\binom{16}{6} = 8008$;
$\binom{39}{3} = 9139$, $\binom{39}{4} = 82251$, $\binom{703}{2} = 246753$

Answer (score 8):

This is not a complete answer, but it does address a simpler question raised by YCor in the comments. For the sake of clarity, the question asked by YCor is whether there exist only geometric progressions of bounded length among the binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{n}{2}$. On that front, there are answers. The latest result I am aware of is due to Bennett and Siksek ([Rational points on Erdos-Selfridge superelliptic curves](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/rational-points-on-erdosselfridge-superelliptic-curves/1C53006D003585C6F4746BE4E0162836)): they proved that for any $k \geq 2$ there are only finitely many $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\ell \geq 3$ such that the equation

$$\displaystyle x(x+1) \cdots (x + k - 1) = y^\ell$$

holds (note that $\ell$ is part of the finiteness claim: $\ell$ is variable in the above set-up, not fixed). In principle their methods should be adaptable to also work with the polynomial $x(x+1)/2$ on the left hand side. Further, it should be possible to adapt their work to treat the more general equation with a fixed $a$ on the right hand side, that is, the equation $x(x+1)/2 = a y^\ell$ with $a$ fixed.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the result of Bennett and Siksek.

Comment: How do these results address the question of geometric progressions among the $\binom n2$?